# Loadbalancing using PHP? Is this effective?

Tags: php, dns, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

Server 1:

```
<?php 
$servers = array("server2", 
              "server3", 
              "server4"); 
$server = $servers[array_rand($servers)]; 
header("Location: http://$server"); 
?>
```

Server 2:

**Cloned Website**

Server 3:

**Cloned Website**

Server 4:

**Cloned Website**

Server 5:

### **Database server, serving all servers**

The DNS will be set to server 1 and then the script will redirect them to a random server in order to lower the load.

I could load up multiple server 1's using roundrobin DNS for example.

Furthermore I could improve the script on server 1 to check the health status every so often in order to make sure it doesn't redirect to a server that has gone down.

This could surely balance an unlimited amount of servers, I could just keep spinning up more loadbalancing servers via DNS if the load is super high? I don't see a problem with this, but clearly there must be as nobody uses this method

**What I wanted to know is that would this be a good approach to loadbalancing, if not how exactly should it be done? Is there any problems with this approach?**

Comment: Why not use nginx as a load balancer?

Comment: I know, but I just want to know if there is hypothetically any issue with doing this instead of using NGINX, as this is a much simpler method to implement.

Comment: Using a scripting language as a load balancer is going to be a lot slower, and is probably one of the most serious reinventing-the-wheel cases I can think of. But if you're doing it as a learning experiment, then good luck - there's no fundamental reason it can't be done.

Comment: @iainn What would be the effect of this if I am already using it in a fairly large website that get's tens of thousands of hits an hour?

Comment: @Destroyer Well if you're using an actual HTTP redirect rather than proxying the requests then the obvious drawback is that you won't be able to use anything other than GET requests. If you're using this for anything more complicated than serving basic static content then that might be a show-stopper straight away. I really, *really* wouldn't recommend using anything like this in production, let alone for a large website. Apache, nginx, haproxy, even DNS round-robin are going to be far more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

At the first place most of the server load rely on Sql and heavy query, 
So instead of making multiple servers to handle request. You can do this

1. Make Sql replica (Slave server) use it for reading and user master for writing.
2. Use Memcache or Redis to prevent getting common data from database all the time.
3. Prevent Unnecessary load/query.
4. Use CDN